# what to do with super in java?

Tags: java, inheritance

I was asked to do this:

> Design
>   and implement a class called MonetaryCoin that is derived from the Coin class
>   presented in Chapter 5. Store a value in the monetary coin that represents its value
>   and add getter and setter methods for the monetary value.

The Coin class is as follows:

```
public class Coin
    { 
        public final int HEADS = 0; 
        public final int TAILS = 1; 
        private int face; 
        // --------------------------------------------- 
        // Sets up the coin by flipping it initially. 
        // --------------------------------------------- 
        public Coin () 
        { 
            flip(); 
         } 
         // -----------------------------------------------
        // Flips the coin by randomly choosing a face.
        // ----------------------------------------------- 
        public void flip() 
        { 
            face = (int) (Math.random() * 2); 
        } 
        // --------------------------------------------------------- 
        // Returns true if the current face of the coin is heads. 
        // ---------------------------------------------------------


        public boolean isHeads() 
        {
            return (face == HEADS); 
        } 


 // ---------------------------------------------------- 
 // Returns the current face of the coin as a string. 
 // ---------------------------------------------------- 


        public String toString() 
        { 
            String faceName; 

            if (face == HEADS) 
                faceName = "Heads";

            else
                faceName = "Tails";

            return faceName; 
        } 
}
```

I came up with this:

```
public class MonetaryCoinHW extends Coin
{

public MonetaryCoinHW(int face)
{
    setFace(face);
}

public int getFace()
{
    if (isHeads()) {
                    return HEADS;
                }
                return TAILS;
}

public void setFace( int newFace )
{
    while (newFace != getFace()) {
                     flip();
                }
      }
```

However, I keep getting syntax errors... Am I not using "super" correctly? I am completely confused; what is my mistake?

Comment: you miss a corresponding constructor in your super class Coin when you try to call it. Coin(int face) {...} http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: Based on your problem statement, I don't understand why you're trying to couple the face variable in Coin: representing if the coin is heads or tails, with the value of the MonetaryCoin.  The superclass Coin does not have any notion of value, because that's the whole reason MonetaryCoin exists.  So obviously MonetaryCoin needs a separate "value" property of its own.

Comment: Please do not edit your question in a way that new comer will lose what you are asking about.  Obviously in your original code you have something like `super()` but you removed it now.  How do you expect other people to know what you are asking then?

Answer (score 4):

No, you are not using `super()` correctly.

`super()` calls the superconstructor - in this case, it will call the inherited `Coin()`. Since no constructor exists inside `Coin()` for `Coin(int face)`, your subclass can't invoke it.

There are to ways to deal with this. I believe you need to run `setFace(face)`. This will properly initialize the value of the coin, and I think fits your problem the best. However, you could also add the `Coin(int face)` constructor to the `Coin` class. You would also have to give the `Coin` a way to hold a value, though.

Comment: ok, then how would I go about doing this, because Im completely lost, and Ive been looking at this same question for literaly the past hr or 2. so in order to store a value would I have to create a whole new variable and do something like this:


public class MonetaryCoinHW extends Coin
{
 private int value;
 public MonetaryCoinHW(int value)
 {
  this.value=value;
 }

 public int getFace()
 {
  return value;
 }
 
 public void setFace( int face )
 {
  value = face;
 }
}

Comment: im sorry im just completely confused on what to do

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what you need to do. The implementation of `Coin` needs a variable to hold the coin's value. Then, you can use `setFace` in the constructor to initialize the face of the coin.

Answer (score 0):

The class coin needs to have the following constructor for your sub-class to work correctly.

```
public Coin(int face) {
    this.face = face;
}
```

This will solve the problem super(face).

Answer (score 0):

No you are not calling super correctly.
You need to have constructor of coin with one argument that is int.
i.e.

```
public Coin (int face) 
{ 
      this.face = face;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Either**

**remove** the `super(face)` line from you class `MonetaryCoinHW`. And simple call **setFace(face)**. But also note that the face variable is defined private in your super class so you cannot access it.

**By default it will call the no argument constructor of super class.**

**OR**

define `Coin(int face)` constructor in class `Coin`

You only need to define the special constructor in Coin class if you want to do something different.

Comment: I cant mess with the super class because the class was provided by the prof and I was told to create the sub class deriving from it

Comment: What your sub class suppose to do? The face variable is private in super class so you cannot change it. What you want to achieve?

Comment: Well I first had to:
Design and implement a class called MonetaryCoin that is derived from the Coin class presented in Chapter 5. Store a value in the monetary coin that represents its value and add getter and setter methods for the monetary value.


Then I need to:

Create a main driver class to instantiate 25 monetary coins with random
monetary values. The driver flips all the coins, computes and prints to the
screen the average monetary value of all coins with TAILS face


But I dont even know if I did the first part correctly yet

Comment: Since the face is private and no access given to change it try this -> Remove super(face) instead Call setFace(face). In the setFace(int newFace) call flip() until isHeads() matches with the newFace. You should use the HEADS & TAILS constant to check that. Change the getFace() method to use isHeads() method to return the current face.

Comment: I know this is asking for a lot but could someone just show me how it should be done? I would learn alot from looking exactly what is needed to be done... thank you so much for the help again guys

Comment: Read my comment where I explained what you can do with the restrictions of your super class.

Comment: I did but still a little confused, could u please edit my code on top to see exactly what to do?

Sorry and thank you